# Running test code after MainWindow complete

Tags: c#, wpf

When I need to try some c# WPF code I often create a new application with a button and I put my test code inside the `Button_Click` event. Then I set a breakpoint in the `Button_Click` event, run the application, click on the button and check my code with the debugger.

That's ok but I wonder what's the correct way to make the same avoiding the button. That is: when I run the application and after that MainWindow get completely executed I would like that the execution continues with my test code (in a method).

P.S. This question is for a WPF GUI application. Otherwise, I know I could use a console application...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Loaded event:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
    }

    private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //your code
    }
}
```